# vim copy command to clipboard / buffer

Tags: vim

How to copy the ex command to the clipboard or paste it to the buffer?

Using gvim on Windows.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The windows clipboard can be accessed through [the buffer `+`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers). So pasting your clipboard as an ex-command can be done with `<C-R>+`. If you want to copy your ex-commands to the clipboard, you need to show the command history (`q:`) and copy it into the clipboard buffer (`"+yy`).

Comment: <C-R>+ works to paste into the ex-command line.
But How do I copy the ex-command into the clipboard?

Comment: I presume you can reach command history with
    
    q:

from normal mode or

    <C-F>

from ex-command mode. (:<C-F>)

Comment: Aaah.  Didn't know about the ex-history window.  Exactly what I need.

Comment: What about copying text you've entered into the command line, but haven't executed it yet and don't want to. How do you copy it then?

Comment: @trusktr at that point, I think you'd convert your not-yet-command into a command that sets a register to the command you don't intend to execute.  or make it into a comment line and pull it out of history as is described elsewhere here.

Answer (score 19):

Enter command history with (from normal mode)

```
q:
```

Then select and copy(yank) commands you need with

```
"*y
```

Answer (score 13):

To copy the last executed command to your clipboard:

```
:let @+=@:
```

Essentially assign the *command (:)* register to the *system clipboard (+)* register.

Answer (score 9):

```
:call setreg('+', getreg(':'))
```

Answer (score 3):

not exactly an answer to the question, but on the same lines, the command    `":p`    will put/paste the last ex command into the file. it can then be yanked into the clipboard with the command     `V"+yy`

 neither of these will open another window.
they are also useful for when you come up with a really good really long command that you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

If you source mswin.vim in your setup it will map the default Windows copy/paste keys to use the clipboard. If you want to do it yourself please see Soulmerge's answer.

Comment: Problem is that I cannot select the command to copy it.  I use the mouse to select, and then that works, but it's not really the vim way.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Normal move commands work with yank. If you want something more fancy, you can use visual mode (v/V)

Comment: I didn't know about the ex-command history Window. SO it did not make sense at first.  Now it it does.